# Accidentally executed 'sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /' Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu

Was trying to change the ownership of a folder but executed this command

```
root@xyz.com:~# chown -R www-data:www-data /
```

The entire directory structure under '/' got changed.
Upon realising the mistake I executed this command

```
root@xyz.com:~# chown -R root:root /
```

Now I am unable to execute php scripts as apache user. Mysql is unable to find an existing database (shows 'unknown database'). Not sure what else got broken.

Comment: You won't be able to fix that system since you have lost all the ownership information of the whole file system content. You might be able to still use parts of the system, but most services will run into issues and trying to fix all that by hand is something you do not really want to start with. So fetch the backups and start from the last point you wrote the backup.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48845/how-to-revert-chown-command

Comment: there are no accidents with sudo. You were just subconsciously ready to rebuild this system from scratch. ;)